# How to pass parameters in URL of the query string using dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have written a small piece of code for passing the parameters in the query string. This function is going to pass the single parameter only. But i want to pass  multiple parameters. So can any one help me out how to pass extra parameters like p, q and r.

Here is my piece of code:

```
searchTabLoaded: function() {
      var tmpQS = this.getQueryString();
      if ( tmpQS.hasOwnProperty('p') ) {
          var tmpProgram = decodeURIComponent(tmpQS['p']);
          this.searchTab.doSearch({'program': tmpProgram}, true);
          return;
      }
}
```

The above code is when i pass a parameter in the url like http://localhost/abc/def/sessions/?p=Something%20Here

Then it will load the desired results in a tab. But i want to pass multiple parameters like

http://localhost/abc/def/sessions/?p=Something%20Here&q=Some%20More%20Stuff&r=More%20More%20Stuff

Like above URL i want to construct depends on the parameters we pass in the URL.

The doSearch() function:

```
doSearch: function(theQuery, tmpPublishWhenDone) {
      console.log("Query: " + dojo.toJson(theQuery));
      this.startSearch();
    // get values from known widgets
    var tmpROUTINE = "doSearch";
    //WJF - If we have multi values in the query, we need to go "complex"
    var tmpQuery = theQuery || {};

    var tmpResultsDesc = this.getQueryDescription(tmpQuery);

    if (this._containsArray(tmpQuery)){
        //--- We need a complex query
        tmpQuery = this.convertToComplexQuery(tmpQuery);
    }

    var sortAttributes = this.getCurrentSortAttributes();

    var tmpResultsTitle = 'Search Results';
    var tmpToRun = this.publishResults;
    if( tmpPublishWhenDone == false ){
        tmpToRun = this.setResults;
    }

    var ds = this.getDS();

    var keywordArgs = {
          query: tmpQuery,
          resultsTitle: tmpResultsTitle,
          resultsDesc: tmpResultsDesc,
          sort: sortAttributes,
          onComplete: dojo.hitch(this,tmpToRun),
          onError: function(error) {
            // handle error
            console.error("query failed: ", error.message);
          },
          queryOptions: {
            ignoreCase:true,
            deep: true
          }
    };
    this.lastQuery = keywordArgs;

    try {
        ds.fetch(keywordArgs);      
    } catch(ex){

        this.processError(tmpROUTINE, ex, "running fetch with args -> " + typeof keywordArgs);      
    }

  }
```

This below function will get the query string.

```
getQueryString : function () {
      //--- also adds lower version to check
      var query_string = {};
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        var tmpKey = '' + pair[0];
        var tmpKeyLower = tmpKey.toLowerCase();
            // If first entry with this name
        if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
          query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            // If second entry with this name
        } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
          var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
          query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
            // If third or later entry with this name
        } else {
          query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
        }
        if( tmpKey != tmpKeyLower ){
            query_string[tmpKeyLower] = query_string[tmpKey];
        }

      } 
        return query_string;
  }
```

Can anybody help me out using Dojo?

Thanks..

Comment: Have a look at the [dojo/request](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/ajax/index.html) tutorial for making a get request with parameters.

Comment: Hey Frank, actually i am using dojo 1.6 version. Do you have any suggestions for this.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the query string of the current URL, or how to pass query string parameters in XHRs for other URLs?

Comment: [dojo/request 1.6](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/ajax/) Ajax tutorial

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro: Actually in this.searchTab.doSearch({'program': tmpProgram}, true), i am passing only one parameter but here i want to pass more two parameters like this this.searchTab.doSearch({'program': tmpProgram, 'track': tmpProgram, 'track2': tmpProgram}, true);  Is it possible? Because i want to load three parameters values in the search Tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create query parameters from Javascript object using dojo's objectToquery method.

Refer this: 
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/objectToQuery.html